# c++ why the following variable doesn't go through virtual table

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Assume we have a code like this:

```
struct X{
   virtual void foo(){}
};

struct Y: X{
   void foo() override{}
}
```

And we do something like this:

```
void test(Y& ref){
   Y local_y;
   local_y.foo();
   ref.foo();
}
```

In the first call (in some compiler), the first call won't go through the `vptr` at all, while the second one will.

That made sense to me because from what I know only references and pointers are polymorphic in c++, while regular variables aren't, so there is no need to through the table.

However the reason stated for that was that it is a compiler optimization because `local_y` is on the stack. So the compiler knew not to go through the virtual table.

Although the reasons are similar (and may be the same) I am wondering - does what I thought make sense? Also, would `local_y` even have a `vptr`? (I assume the answer is yes, because we may do `Y& new_y=local_y`, and `new_y` would need to have that pointer).

Comment: I advise you stop fixating on implementation details. If the compiler doesn't need to do a thing, it won't do a thing. Your code _describes a program_. You're not programming a computer; that's your compiler's job.

Comment: Why would `ref.foo()` go through the `vptr`? From your example, it doesn't look like `Y` is a polymorphic class. Did you mean `void test(X& ref) {`?

Comment: The correct `foo` function should be called in both cases. How the compiler ends up calling it is an implementation internal detail. Whether it will or "*won't go through the vptr*" is immaterial, and the C++ language standard does not even define or require a "*vptr*".

Comment: @scohe001 In what way is `Y` not a polymorphic class? And what if `Y& ref` refers to a `Z`?

Comment: Ahh looks like inheriting a polymorphic function makes you polymorphic yourself (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects). I wasn't aware of that. Good call @Asteroids.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Well, I have a class that focuses exactly on those things, so this isn't really my choice.

Comment: @EL_9 I'm sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That made sense to me because from what I know only references and pointers are polymorphic in c++, while regular variables aren't, so there is no need to through the table.
>
> does what I thought make sense?

No. Runtime polymorphism isn't somehow "disabled" for "regular variables". A virtual function is a virtual function, and runtime polymorphism is applied when you invoke a virtual function. Period.

People like to say "runtime polymorphism only works with references and pointers" because, syntactically, it's difficult to find counter-examples without slicing off the derived parts of your object.

In your case, you don't even *need* virtual dispatch (you're literally just calling the function that you want to be called) so the entire point is moot.

> However the reason stated for that was that it is a compiler optimization because local_y is on the stack. So the compiler knew not to go through the virtual table.

That makes more sense. It is trivially provable that the object called `local_y` is of dynamic type `Y`, because its declaration is right there in the function. So there's no need for any magical antics beyond literally just calling the function `foo()` that's defined in `Y`.

You could call that an "optimisation"; I call it "the compiler doing its job without unnecessary steps".

> Would local_y even have a vptr?

Probably, but only because a compiler isn't going to gain much by selectively altering parts of class definitions based on local usage.

Comment: Whether or not it has a vptr depends on the optimization settings. At -O2 or above it does not even generate `y_local` never mind it's vptr. See https://godbolt.org/z/7cbe3P

Comment: Would an object that is not a pointer or a reference will ever go through its dynamic table when a function is invoked on it?

Comment: @EL_9 No, and that's why people mistakenly think that polymorphism "only works" with pointers. The truth is that it's only _needed_ with pointers. If the dynamic type is statically known, no magic is required. Also bear in mind that vtables are an implementation detail.